# How can i put NSArray into XML file and upload to URL

Tags: xml, xcode, nsarray

I am working in xcode; I have an NSArray of data that I want to convert into an XML file and then upload to a web database.

The array is formatted like this:

`555ttt Conor Brady testpass BC test Desc this is user timestamp this is location this is user location`

I want it to convert into XML file, as shown below:

```
<plates>
<plate>
<plateno>555ttt</plateno>
<user>Conor Brady</user>
<username>cbrady</username>
<password>testpass</password>
<province>BC</province>
<description>test desc</description>
<usertimestamp>this is user timestamp</usertimestamp>
<location>this is user location</location>
<status>this is user status</status>
</plate>
<plate>
<plateno>333yyy</plateno>
<user>C Brady</user>
<username>cbrady</username>
<password>testpass</password>
<province>BC</province>
<description>This is a test description</description>
<usertimestamp>this is user timestamp</usertimestamp>
<location>this is user location</location>
<status>this is user status</status>
</plate>
</plates>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a mapping from the data in your array to tags in the XML you want to generate. The easiest way to do this is by creating a dictionary for each plate you want to add to your XML. Something like this should do the trick:

```
// Encode the data in an array of dictionaries
// Each dictionary has a key indentifying the XML tag
NSDictionary *plate1 = @{@"plateno" : @"555ttt", @"user" : @"Conor Brady", @"password" : @"testpass", @"province" : @"BC", @"description" : @"test desc", @"location" : @"this is user location"};
NSDictionary *plate2 = @{@"plateno" : @"333yyy", @"user" : @"C Brady", @"password" : @"testpass", @"province" : @"BC", @"description" : @"test desc", @"location" : @"this is user location"};
NSArray *platesData = @[plate1, plate2];

// Build the XML string
NSMutableString *xmlString = [NSMutableString string];

// Start the plates data
[xmlString appendString:@"<plates>"];

for (NSDictionary *plateDict in platesData) {
    // Start a plate entry
    [xmlString appendString:@"<plate>"];

    // Add all the keys (XML tags) and values to the string
    [plateDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop){
        [xmlString appendFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>", key, value, key];
    }];

    // End a plate entry
    [xmlString appendString:@"</plate>"];
}

// End the plates data
[xmlString appendString:@"</plates>"];
```